# Nested loop in python to produce cartesian product

Tags: python

I am trying to loop through two list in python to get a output like this.

```
list1 = [a, b, c]
list2 = [1, 2, 3]
```

So it should loop for each value of list1 over list 2. list1[a] will loop 3 times over list2 and so on till it reaches c. However, I am not getting the desired output.

```
i=''
list1 = ['ABC ' + str(i)+ ' '+'1' + ' ' + '5', 'CDE '+ str(i)+ ' '+  '1'+ ' ' + '5']
list2=['123','234','456']
for c in list1:
         for i in list2:
               print c
```

Output:

```
ABC  1 5
ABC  1 5
ABC  1 5
CDE  1 5
CDE  1 5
CDE  1 5
```

Desired out put should be like below:

```
ABC 123 1 5
CDE 123 1 5
ABC 234 1 5
CDE 234 1 5
ABC 456 1 5
CDE 456 1 5
```

Please guide me what I am missing here, am new with this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to interpolate the `list2` value inside the loop. You could the [`itertools.product()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) instead of nesting your loops; do swap the order of the lists if you want the values of `list1` to alterate:

```
from itertools import product

list1 = ['ABC {} 1 5', 'CDE {} 1 5']
list2 = ['123','234','456']
for l2, l1 in product(list2, list1):
    print l1.format(l2)
```

The [`str.format()` method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) fills the `{}` in the `list1` strings with your `l2` values, letting you avoid having to rebuild `list2` from scratch each time:

```
>>> for l2, l1 in product(list2, list1):
...     print(l1.format(l2))
...
ABC 123 1 5
CDE 123 1 5
ABC 234 1 5
CDE 234 1 5
ABC 456 1 5
CDE 456 1 5
```

Another alternative is for `list1` to contain *tuples* of values to be used, and only when printing you convert everything to one string by using `print()` as a function (Python 3, or a `from __future__` import in Python 2):

```
from __future__ import print_function

list1 = [('ABC', 1, 5), ('CDE', 1, 5)]
list2 = ['123','234','456']
for l2, (a, b, c) in product(list2, list1):
    print(a, l2, b, c)
```

It depends on what else you want to do with the values produced.

Note that if the `1` and `5` numbers are otherwise unchanged between the values of `list1`, there is no need at all to do a complicated dance with string templates or tuples. You'd just reference those inside the loop:

```
b, c = 1, 5
list1 = ['ABC', 'CDE']
list2 = ['123','234','456']
for l2, l1 in product(list2, list1):
    print '{} {} {} {}'.format(l1, l2, b, c)
```

I still used string formatting just to show another form of combining several values into one string.

Answer (score 1):

You need to move the construction of `list1` into your for loop. Reorganize your lines as follows:

```
list2 = ['123', '234', '456']

for i in list2:
    list1 = ['ABC ' + str(i) + ' ' + '1' + ' ' + '5',
             'CDE ' + str(i) + ' ' + '1' + ' ' + '5']
    for c in list1:
        print c
```

this will print

```
ABC 123 1 5
CDE 123 1 5
ABC 234 1 5
CDE 234 1 5
ABC 456 1 5
CDE 456 1 5
```

That being said, this can be improved using [string formatting](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.format):

```
for i in list2:
    list1 = ['ABC {0} 1 5', 'CDE {0} 1 5']
    for c in list1:
        print c.format(i)
```

Comment: Why not use string templating?

Comment: @MartijnPieters I just pointed out the error in OPs code for them to understand what was wrong with it. I was going to post an improved version but you already beat me to it.

Comment: Do feel free to keep editing anyway! Future visitors would probably appreciate another perspective.